# Remove elements in a flat array where the next element is not a price value

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, currency

I have a large array of scraped names and prices similar to the following:

```
Array(
  [0] => apple3
  [1] => £0.40
  [2] => banana6
  [3] => £1.80
  [4] => lemon
  [5] => grape
  [6] => pear5
  [7] => melon4
  [8] => £2.32
  [9] => kiwi
  [10] => £0.50
)
```

I would like to remove the fruit names that are not immediately followed by a price.  In the above example this would remove: `[4] => lemon [5] => grape [6] => pear5` resulting in the following output:

```
Array(
  [0] => apple3
  [1] => £0.40
  [2] => banana6
  [3] => £1.80
  [7] => melon4
  [8] => £2.32
  [9] => kiwi
  [10] => £0.50
)
```

If the array needs to be converted to a string in order for me to do this that is not a problem, nor is adding values between the array items in order to aid with regex searches.  I have so far been unable to find the correct regular expression to do this using `preg_match()` and `preg_replace()`.

The most important factor is the need to maintain the sequential order of the fruits and prices in order for me at a later stage to convert this into an associative array of fruits and prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does both of your tasks at once: getting rid of the fruit without value and turning the result into an associative array of fruits with prices.

```
$arr = array('apple', '£0.40', 'banana', '£1.80', 'lemon', 'grape', 'pear', 'melon', '£2.32', 'kiwi', '£0.50' );

preg_match_all( '/#?([^£][^#]+)#(£\d+\.\d{2})#?/', implode( '#', $arr ), $pairs );
$final = array_combine( $pairs[1], $pairs[2] );

print_r( $final );
```

First, the array is converted to a string, separated by '#'. The regex captures all groups of fruits with prices - each stored as a separate subgroup in the result. Combining them into an associative array is a single function call.

Answer (score 4):

Why involve regular expressions? This is doable with a simple `foreach` loop wherein you iterate over the array and remove names that follow names:

```
$lastWasPrice = true; // was the last item a price?
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (ctype_alpha($v)) {
        // it's a name
        if (!$lastWasPrice) {
            unset($array[$k]); // name follows name; remove the second
        }
        $lastWasPrice = false;
    }
    else {
        // it's a price
        $lastWasPrice = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately i forgot to add numbers to the fruits which more accurately reflects the problem i am facing.  Can this code be altered to reflect this change? Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @RajGundu: Sure, just replace `ctype_alpha` with a function of your own that recognizes names (or invert the logic and use a function that recognizes prices) based on your actual values.

Comment: This won't technically work because if a name follows a name, you want to remove the previous one, as the second one may have a price following it.

Comment: @Jon: That's true, but it's really not that difficult to adapt the code to match the requirements. You just have to change the state being kept (here `$lastWasPrice` is the bare minimum that works).

Comment: @Jon That is true.  Just felt that it needed to be said so the entirety of the answer wasn't immediately scrapped because it produced a result different than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this :

```
  <?php
for($i=0;$i<count($my_array);$i++)
{
if($my_array[$i+1]value=="")
unset($my_array[$i])
}
?>
```

Comment: It needs to be compared to the value prior to see if it contains a fruit - your approach is checking each individual key (it's an indexed array, `$key=0` when `$value='apple'`).  A `foreach` loop won't be able to accomplish what is being asked unless you use `$myArray[$key-1]` knowing that all keys are integers.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately i forgot to add numbers to the fruits which more accurately reflects the problem i am facing. Can this code be altered to reflect this change? Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: what do you mean by that?put a little part as a comment here

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you

```
$array = ...;
$index = 0;

while (isset($array[$index + 1])) {
  if (!is_fruit($array[$index + 1])) {
    // Not followed by a fruit, continue to next pair
    $index += 2;
  } else {
    unset($array[$index]);  // Will maintain indices in array
    $index += 1;
  }
}
```

Not tested though. Also, you need to create the function `is_fruit` yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without reformatting it, I don't think you can do it with `preg_match` or `preg_replace`-- maybe, but nothing is coming to mind.

What is creating that array? If possible, I would alter it to look more like:

```
Array([apple] => £0.40 [banana] => £1.80 [lemon] => [grape] => '' [pear ] => '' [melon  => £2.32 [kiwi] => £0.50)
```

Then `array_filter($array)` is all you'd need to clean it up. If you can't alter the way the original array is created I'd lean towards creating key/value array out of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the pattern ** => ([a-zA-Z])** with ** => £0.00 $1**

Basically searching for the context where there is null price and inserting zero pounds.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately i forgot to add numbers to the fruits which more accurately reflects the problem i am facing. Can this code be altered to reflect this change? Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Yes, just use number ranges in your regular expression. [0-9] defines any number. Add ranges to cover multiple digits and use a "?" if the digits do not always occur.

Answer (score 0):

assume `$a` is your array.

```
function isPrice($str) {
    return (substr($str, 0, 1) == '£');
}
$newA = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
    if( isPrice($a[$i]) != isPrice($a[$i+1]) ){
        $newA[] = $a[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `unset()`ing, it may be clearer to human readers of your code to conditionally push pairs of elements into a result array and preserve the original keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cofX1))

```
$array = ['apple3', '£0.40', 'banana6', '£1.80', 'lemon', 'grape', 'pear5', 'melon4', '£2.32', 'kiwi', '£0.50'];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    if (mb_substr($v, 0, 1) === '£') {
        $result[$i - 1] = $array[$i - 1];
        $result[$i] = $v;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```